# mysql ORDER BY IF ELSE

Tags: mysql

I was thinking if there is some more advanced way to use `ORDER BY` in mysql query.

I have query to get products from db, using order by price.
The problem is  if discount value not null, it overrides the main price, and it should somehow
override the `ORDER BY` line.

**IDEA:**

```
DESC

product_price discount
900           0
800           0
1200          700 //dicount overrides price
600           0
```

The query got 25 lines, but the logic is something like this:

```
SELECT
product_price as price,
IFNULL(discount_amount,0) as discount

FROM not_relevant

WHERE not_relevant

ORDER BY product_price DESC
```

So when i write products to category sort by price, certain products have discount so the main price is overwritten and sort only by price is not accurate.

I tried to use `coalesce`, or two `ORDER BY`.

Any ideas?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you want your results to look like? Not clear from your wording

Comment: To defaultly sort by price, but if discount not null use the discount value instead of price value, hope its more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
SELECT
product_price,
IFNULL(discount_amount,0) as discount,
IFNULL(discount_amount,product_price) as price

FROM not_relevant

WHERE not_relevant

ORDER BY price DESC
```

It basically does what you're asking... If `discount` is not null it will be used, else it uses `product_price`, and orders the results.

Comment: `discount` isn't the name of a field in the original query. If you want to use the aliased column `discount` then the value will never be NULL

Answer (score 1):

This can be used if discount is actually discounted price and not discount amount

```
SELECT product_price as price,
IFNULL(discount_amount,0) as discount

FROM not_relevant
    ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN discount_amount IS NULL THEN price ELSE discount_amount END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_price As price
     , Coalesce(discount_amount, 0) As discount
     , Coalesce(discount_amount, product_price) As order_by_this
FROM   not_relevant
WHERE  not_relevant
ORDER
    BY order_by_this
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT product_price As price
     , Coalesce(discount_amount, 0) As discount
FROM   not_relevant
WHERE  not_relevant
ORDER
    BY Coalesce(discount_amount, product_price)
```

Comment: I thought coalesce is oracle-only, good to learn that its more common, nice idea

Comment: @skv:  `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard SQL and available in almost all databases.

Comment: @skv `Coalesce()` is the ANSI/ISO (sorry, forget which) standard function. Just one more reason why you should always use this over vendor-specific options